# How to get wrapped text from Excel cell?

Tags: c#, closedxml

I want to know how to get wrapped text from Excel cell using ClosedXML.

(ClosedXML version is 0.95.4, and use C#[Visualstudio 2017])

For example:
excel cell data (text) is following

```
abc
xyz
```

I want

```
abc
xyz
```

(=wrapped text), but I get `abcxyz` (=no wrapped text).

I tried several methods (as follows) and the results were the same.

```
tgtcell.RichText
tgtcell.GetString()
tgtcell.Value.ToString()
```

etc.

Can anyone tell me how to get it?

Comment: Why is it _"wrapped"_? I'm curious. Have you checked that there's no non-printing character between the `abc` and the `xyz` (for example, have you checked the `Length` property of the string you get

Comment: It's wrapped because it's an input file presented by someone else.

Comment: I checked the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Now the cause is known. In the cell where the wrapped text was entered, the unwrapped one was mixed in. (Wrapped only by specifying the style format.)
Unfortunately, it was the cell that I tested, so it looked unreadable.

Comment: The way to close this question is, once you're able to, mark your answer as "accepted". That will communicate to others that this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

*(this is more of an extended comment than a definitive answer)*

I created an Excel file in which I typed `ABC<Alt>+<Enter>xyz` in cell A1.  That puts `ABC` on one line and `xyz` under it (all in the same cell).  Then I saved it and closed Excel.

Then I opened the file in the Microsoft "OpenXML Productivity Tool" (which unfortunately has been taken down from "Microsoft.com" but is still available on GitHub).

If I look in the Shared Strings section of the file, I can see this as XML:

```
<x:sst count="1" uniqueCount="1" xmlns:x="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">
  <x:si>
    <x:t>ABCxyz</x:t>
  </x:si>
</x:sst>
```

But, if I look at the reflected code (reflected into C#), I see:

```
public class GeneratedClass
{
    // Creates an SharedStringTable instance and adds its children.
    public SharedStringTable GenerateSharedStringTable()
    {
        SharedStringTable sharedStringTable1 = new SharedStringTable(){ Count = (UInt32Value)1U, UniqueCount = (UInt32Value)1U };

        SharedStringItem sharedStringItem1 = new SharedStringItem();
        Text text1 = new Text();
        text1.Text = "ABC\nxyz";

        sharedStringItem1.Append(text1);

        sharedStringTable1.Append(sharedStringItem1);
        return sharedStringTable1;
    }
}
```

So it looks like Excel stores a Unix newline character between lines in a single cell.  I don't know why that doesn't show up in the XML.

I'm far from an OpenXML expert, but I have used it several times successfully (mostly to generate files, not to parse them).  I've never used ClosedXML.  I don't have a clue what *Wrapped Text* means (nor does your explanation help).  But, I can see the two lines of text in the file.

I don't know if this will help you - I hope so.